# How to add json values in single row of autocompletetextview?

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

I am using this [example](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-autocompletetextview-example-json/) of autocompletetextview,now i am able to get name in suggestion,the output is like

ab
abc

but the issue is i want to get id and name in single row,like

1 ab
2 abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to append id also with name. Have a look at following code:

```
 @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
                if (constraint != null) {

                    List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions =jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                    suggestions.clear();
                    for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                        //  Append id and name here 
                        suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getId()+" "+new_suggestions.get(i).getName());
                    }


                    filterResults.values = suggestions;
                    filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }
```

Comment: accepted and vote up..and can you tell what if two names is there?

Comment: can you tell how can i get some spaces between those two strings.it shows right now..1 ab...can i have 1     ab?

Comment: Look for ` suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getId()+" "+new_suggestions.get(i).getName());` this line. Add whatever you want to add.